# Python SUM_WITH_FLAG

Tags: python, sum

I entered to my college newly in recent and my major is CS.
I am very struggling with python programming and I need you guys help very seriously!

def sum_with_flag(alist,flag):

''' sum_with_flag(list,int) -> int

```
Returns the sum of all elements in the list.  When `flag` is 
   seen in the list, `flag` is not added to the list. Additionally
   everything after `flag` is not added to the list until `flag` is 
   seen again.  In general, a number is added to the list only if 
   it is not equal to flag and there are an even number of occurances
   of flag before it.

For example, if `flag` is 12

   [1,12,5,7,12,8,12,1]

The function returns 1+8 = 9.
1 is counted 
12 is flag, so 5 and 7 are not counted
12 is flag, so we count 8
12 is flag, so we do not count 1
```

> > > sum_with_flag([1,12, 5, 7, 12, 8, 12, 1], 12)

9

> > > sum_with_flag([1, 2, 3, 4], 0)

10

> > > sum_with_flag([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)

1

> > > sum_with_flag([1, 2, 1, 2, 1], 2)

2

> > > sum_with_flag([1, 2, 1], 1)

0

> > > sum_with_flag([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1], 1)

4

'''

And here is my code.

```
for each in alist:
    if each == flag:
        del alist[flag:flag]
return sum(alist)
```

What is wrong with mine??

My second code is (it is not completed yet. Because I don't know what to change.)

```
A = True

for each in alist:
    if each == flag:
        A = not A




return sum(alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your function is destructive: it will modify the list passed into it. It is generally bad form to do so unless your function's purpose is to modify the argument.
- In `alist[flag:flag]`, `flag` is treated as an index, but it is a value - it can be outside the index range, and even if not, it doesn't target anything that fits the requirements. E.g. in `sum_with_flag([1,12, 5, 7, 12, 8, 12, 1], 12)`, `alist` doesn't even have 12 elements.
- `del alist[flag:flag]` would delete any elements with `flag <= index < flag`, which is zero elements (given that no `index` is both less than `flag` and greater or equal to it at the same time).

The correct implementation would be to have a boolean variable that tells you whether you're including elements into a sum or not. It would start with a value `True`, indicating that you are. You also need a variable for the running sum, starting at zero. When you encounter an element that is equal to `flag`, you flip this variable. If an element is not equal to flag, then add it to the running sum, but only if you are currently in the adding mode.

Comment: Could you give me some more hint? Sorry this is silly but list is very confusing. I don't even know how to start with boolean

Comment: Any more hint, and I'm coding your assignment for you. I completely spelled out the algorithm in English. Instead, you should indicate if there is any specific part of my explanation that you don't understand. "boolean" means a variable that contains `True` or `False`.

Comment: The main key point I think here is I have to make a new variable which reacts if the alist[] is the same as flag value. Like you said, it need to be like on and off. start with 0 and everytime alist is meeting with flag, it adds 1 to new variable and when the new variable is odd number, it skips alist. Is that correct? Also I would appreciate if there is any similar example that can help me.

Comment: It is a possible way, but it is too complicated. You don't need to count them, you don't need to figure out if they are even or not. All you need to do is say that at the start, `now_summing_stuff = True`; each time you encounter `flag`, `now_summing_stuff = not now_summing_stuff`, and if it's not `flag`, test `if now_summing_stuff` before you add to the running sum.

Comment: A = True

    for each in alist:
        if each == flag:
            A = not A

    return sum(alist)

Am I doing right so far? Oh shoot.. looks like this doesn't get indentation.

Comment: Nope. Forget `sum`; solutions using `sum` are either not as good or much more complicated than you need now. Just go step by step and implement what I said above. For example, you skipped "You also need a variable for the running sum, starting at zero." Also, Python code is legendarily unreadable without indentation; post your further attempts as edits in your original post.

Comment: It is also a personal question. I started programming like few months ago and looks like everyone else in my class is doing fine, not like me. Do you think I seriously need to think about changing my major? I didn't know Computer science class is this hard.

Comment: That I can't tell you - for one, it's individual, for another it's off-topic. But know this: programming, as any creative effort, is 10% inspiration, 90% perspiration. There are things you need to know, and things you need to practice until it's natural, as well as things to be creative about; given that I've given you the creative bit (the algorithm), I assume it's the knowledge and experience you primarily lack. Do you program and read about it outside class? Do your classmates? You can't learn programming in class alone. Hints: reread my algorithm again, see what you skipped, use `else`.